# Javascript zoom on hover without thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

I am looking for a javascript zoom library, similar [this](http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom)
However, most ones out there require that you have thumbnails images for the unzoomed image which is a bit of an annoyance for me since I am only viewing 2-3 images per page and everything is preloaded.

Does anyone know of a similar library which would allow me to do this with a css scaled down version of my image rather than generating the thumnbails in the backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yay for CSS3 transforms:

```
img.thumb {
     -webkit-transform:scale(0.5,0.5);
     -ms-transform:scale(0.5,0.5);
     -moz-transform:scale(0.5,0.5);
     -o-transform:scale(0.5,0.5);
     transform:scale(0.5,0.5);
}
```